# pf, alf, kext order of operation in os x

Tags: osx, firewall, filter

What is the order of operation for the `packet filter`, `application layer firewall` and 3rd party `kexts` and applications like [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html), [Handsoff](http://www.oneperiodic.com/products/handsoff/), [Radio Silence](https://radiosilenceapp.com), [Vallum](https://murusfirewall.com/#vallum) in `OS X`? That is in both inbound and outbound directions and if there's any sort of overriding or precedence in their settings. I skimmed through Apple's developer documentations, but couldn't find a clue to this.